# Cloudwatch Period time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

CPU metrics cannot be selected below 1 minute in Cloudwatch service. For example, how can I lower this period time to trigger the Autoscale scale faster? I just need to trigger the AutoScale instances in short time. (By the way, datapoints value 1 to 1)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct -- basic monitoring of an Amazon EC2 instance provides metrics over 5-minute periods. If you activate **EC2 Detailed Monitoring**, metrics are provided over 1-minute periods. [Extra charges apply](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) for Detailed Monitoring.

When launching a new instance via Amazon EC2 Auto-Scaling, it can take a few minutes for the new instance to launch and for the User Data script (if any) to run. Linux instances are quite fast, but Windows instances take a while on their first boot due to `sysprep` operations.

You mention that you want to react to a metric in less than one minute. I would suggest that this would not be an ideal way to trigger Auto-scaling. Sometimes a computer can be busy for a while, then can drop down again. Reacting too quickly to a high CPU load would cause the Auto-Scaling group to flap between adding instances and terminating instances. It is better to provision enough capacity for a reasonable amount of extra load and then *gradually* add more capacity as it is required over time.

If you have a need to react so quickly, then perhaps you should investigate using AWS Lambda to perform small amounts of work in a highly-parallel fashion rather than relying on Amazon EC2 instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have very aggressive load sometimes, So i need this. I configured already warm pool with hibernate support to quick startup. That s why I m looking for a perfect solution for that

Answer (score 0):

> the minimum granularity for the metrics that EC2 provides is 1 minute.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html

Would also say that if you need to scale that quickly, wouldn't the startup time be an issue anyway?